# MongoDB: find with field-specified date interval

Tags: mongodb-query

SQL example table:

```
| session | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| created | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| ttl     | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
```

If I want to select expired sessions, I can select it over

```
select * from sessions where created < SUBDATE(NOW(), interval ttl minute);
```

A question: how can I do the same request at MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. If 'ttl' is seconds value, I can use:

```
db.sessions.find({$where: "this.ttl!=null && this.created < (new Date()-this.ttl*1000)"}).pretty();
```